# Place a text "general" in blank cells

Tags: excel, is-empty, vba

My code places a text in blank cell but does not fill it up to the boarderline.

I want to place the text "general" in blank cells of Column E but does not fill it up to the end bcoz of the rowcount.

here is my code:

```
Sub FindandReplace()
Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
Dim currentRowValue As String

sourceCol = 5   'column E has a value of 5
rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row

'for every row, find the first blank cell and select it
For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
    currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
    If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
       Cells(currentRow, sourceCol) = "general"
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

The result is this:( still empty column E)

```
Column E                               Column F

general                          Use-Limit
general                          Use-Limit
XL354L,XL354H,XL356L,XL356H          Use-Limit
XL353,XL355,XL357                    Use-Limit
                                 Use-Limit
                                 Use-Limit
                                 Use-Limit
                                 Use-Limit
```

Comment: you have `sourceCol = 5`   'column F has a value of 5, actualy column F has a value of 6, so if you want to use Column F, modify to `sourceCol = 6`

Comment: SOrry that is supposedly column E

Comment: look at my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

**Explanation of your error**: you are looking for last row in **Column E**, which you have 4 rows of data (by looking at your example). However, **Column F** has 8 rows of data. Therefore, if you want to loop through row 8, you need to look for last row in **Column F**, and not Column E.

Try the modified code below:

```
Sub FindandReplace()

Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
Dim currentRowValue As String

sourceCol = 6   ' find last row in column F
rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row

'for every row, find the first blank cell and select it
For currentRow = 1 To rowCount
    currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol-1).Value
    If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
       Cells(currentRow, sourceCol-1) = "general"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hello @shai Rado

Since the sourceCol is 6 that will replace empty cell at Column F and not Column E. I need to replace the empty cells in Column E with "general" and not column F.

Comment: @J_Gonzales you are welcome, mark as answer and upvote

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub FindandReplace()

Dim sourceCol As Integer, rowCount As Integer, currentRow As Integer
Dim currentRowValue As String

sourceCol = 5   ' find last row in column F
rowCount = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol).End(xlUp).Row
rowCount2 = Cells(Rows.Count, sourceCol + 2).End(xlUp).Row ' add this to loop 8 times

'for every row, find the first blank cell and select it
For currentRow = 1 To rowCount2
    currentRowValue = Cells(currentRow, sourceCol).Value
    If IsEmpty(currentRowValue) Or currentRowValue = "" Then
       Cells(currentRow, sourceCol) = "general"
    End If
Next

End Sub
```